# Add to list when list type is not known until runtime

Tags: c#, generics

I have method which accepts an `object`.  This object I know is a `List<T>` however T may vary between children of a base class at any one time when being passed into the method.

So if my base class is `MonthType`, and I have children called `BlockMonthType` and `AreaMonthType` the object passed in could be anyone of `List<BlockMonthType> or List<AreaMonthType>`.

I want to be able to add items to this object however when I cast it it seems to make a copy and the original object is not updated.

I'm doing this to cast:

```
var objectList = ((IEnumerable<MonthType>)graphObject.Source.Object).ToList();
```

Now I want to create a new item and add it to the list

```
// where ObjectType is a Type variable containing BlockMonthType
var newObject = (BlockMonthType)Activator.CreateInstance(graphObject.Source.ObjectType);

objectList.Add(newObject);

// and carry on the world is good
```

This works in so far as objectList has a newObject added. However the original variable isn't updated so when I leave the method it's back to it's original state.  I know the object is a List<> when passed in as I can see it in the debugger as such.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this?

Here is a cut down version of the method I'm using it in.

```
public TraverseGraphResult Write(ObjectGraph graphObject)
{
    var objectList = ((IEnumerable<MonthType>)graphObject.Source.Object).ToList();

    var newObject = (MonthType)Activator.CreateInstance(rule.ObjectType);
    newObject.Month = rule.Month;

    objectList.Add(newObject);

    // Other stuff as well is done but that's the crux of it
}
```

Hopefully this gives it more context.  The method is being used to try and navigate a large object tree with  many class types. I'm trying to add a new class type handler which will deal with adding and removing items from a list.

```
// This is being used in a recursive method to loop down a object's property tree

// .. more code here

// where properties is a List<PropertyInfo>
foreach (var pInfo in properties)
{
    if (IsList(pInfo.PropertyType))
    {
        var enumerable = (IEnumerable)pInfo.GetValue(currentObjectGraph.Source.Object, null);

        var sourceEnumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();          
        var graph = new ObjectGraph(enumerable, pInfo.Name);

        // this part is made up but essentially the code looks up a list of objects that can deal with this 
        // particular one and returns it.  We then call the write method on that object
        var something = GetInterfaceHandlerForObject(enumerable);
        something.Write(graph);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by storing the underlying List T type in the ObjectGraph object and casting to that when required.

```
var objectList = ((IEnumerable)graphObject.Source.Object).Cast(monthAllocationRule.ListType);
```

Without the correct cast objectList was either null or a copy of the list.  Now I can add to objectList and know it's added to the source object.

Probably not idea as Ian mentioned above but did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You should make your method generic:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(List<T> objectList) where T:class, new()
{
    objectList.Add(new T());
    ...
}
```

Casting is rarely ever necessary when you use generics.  Also, your ToList() is causing a new copy of the list to be created.

One drawback to this approach is that `T` needs to have an empty constructor.  If you need to construct an object with parameters you could instead pass in a `Func<T>`.  You can then call it passing in a lambda expression like: `(x) => new BlockMonthType(someParameter, orAnother)`.

Comment: I can't make it generic as it's an implementation of an interface and the interface states it as accepting an object.

Comment: Then you may as well write some clunky code to switch on the type and cast the object to either `List<BlockMonthType>` or `List<AreaMonthType>`.  But why can't you fix the interface, who writes awful interfaces like that?

Comment: Can you post more of the code, especially the interface? Might be helpful to see from where the objectList is originating.

Comment: @Ian Thanks.  I guess so if that's the only way.  It's code I've inherited and it's being used in a recursive object property search and do stuff type operation.  I'm trying to extend it to add a new property.

Comment: I would look at implementing the interface explicitly and then creating good strong generic methods on the class.